# So when i Initialize i get a program error, It worked when i just created it without a txn confirmation

Tags: solana-program, sendtransactionerror

I tested the code without the sendandconfirmtxn and it worked, but then after deploying devnet it stopped working.
this is my program

```
#[program]
pub mod solotesting2 {
    use super::*;

pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
    let mut bluelist_raw = ctx.accounts.bluelist.load_init()?;
    let mut redlist_raw = ctx.accounts.redlist.load_init()?;
    let mut purplelist_raw = ctx.accounts.purplelist.load_init()?;
    let blue = &mut ctx.accounts.blue;
    let red = &mut ctx.accounts.red;
    let purple = &mut ctx.accounts.purple;
    let fees = &mut ctx.accounts.fees;

    let mut bluelist = bluelist_raw.deref_mut();
    let mut redlist = redlist_raw.deref_mut();
    let mut purplelist = purplelist_raw.deref_mut();

    bluelist.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;
    redlist.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;
    purplelist.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;

    blue.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;
    red.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;
    purple.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;
    fees.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;


    bluelist.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("bluelist").unwrap();
    redlist.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("redlist").unwrap();
    purplelist.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("purplelist").unwrap();
    blue.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("blue").unwrap();
    red.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("red").unwrap();
    purple.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("purple").unwrap();
    fees.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("fees").unwrap();


    bluelist.counter = 0;
    redlist.counter = 0;
    purplelist.counter = 0;

    bluelist.total = 0;
    redlist.total = 0;
    purplelist.total = 0;


    Ok(())
}
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        // State account seed uses the string "state" and the users' key. 
        // Note that we can only have 1 active transaction
        seeds = [b"fees",user.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = user, owner = *program_id,
        rent_exempt = enforce,
        // space needs to be adjusted
        space = size_of::<Fees>() + 32 + 8 + 8 + 1
    )]    
    pub fees : Account<'info, Fees>,
    #[account(
        init,
        // State account seed uses the string "state" and the users' key. 
        // Note that we can only have 1 active transaction
        seeds = [b"blue",user.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = user, owner = *program_id,
        // space needs to be adjusted
        space = size_of::<Blue>() + 32 + 8 + 8 + 1
    )]    
    pub blue : Account<'info, Blue>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"red",user.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = user, owner = *program_id,
        // space needs to be adjusted
        space = size_of::<Red>() + 32 + 8 + 8 + 1
    )]  
    pub red : Account<'info, Red>,
    #[account(
        init,
        // State account seed uses the string "state" and the users' key. 
        // Note that we can only have 1 active transaction
        seeds = [b"purple",user.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = user, owner = *program_id,
        // space needs to be adjusted
        space = size_of::<Purple>() + 32 + 8 + 8 + 1
    )]  
    pub purple : Account<'info, Purple>,

    #[account(
        zero,
        seeds = [b"bluelist",user.key().as_ref()],
        owner = *program_id,
        bump
    )]
    
    pub bluelist : AccountLoader<'info, Bluelist>,
    #[account(
        zero,
        seeds = [b"redlist",user.key().as_ref()],
        owner = *program_id,
        bump
    )]
    pub redlist : AccountLoader<'info, Redlist>,
    #[account(
        zero,
        seeds = [b"purplelist",user.key().as_ref()],
        owner = *program_id,
        bump
    )]
    pub purplelist : AccountLoader<'info, Purplelist>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[zero_copy]
pub struct ListEntry {
    pub entry: Pubkey,
    pub deposit: u64,
}

#[account]
pub struct Fees {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub bump: u8,
}

#[account]
pub struct Blue {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub bump: u8,
}

#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(packed)]

pub struct Bluelist {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub bluelist_entry: [ListEntry; 25000],
    pub counter: u64,
    pub total: u64,
    pub bump: u8,
}



#[derive(Accounts)]

pub struct AddBluelistEntry<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub bluelist: AccountLoader<'info, Bluelist>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user : Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub blue : Account<'info,Blue>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Red {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub bump: u8,
}

#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(packed)]

pub struct Redlist {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub redlist_entry: [ListEntry; 25000],
    pub counter: u64,
    pub total: u64,
    pub bump: u8,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct AddRedlistEntry<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub redlist: AccountLoader<'info, Redlist>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user : Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub red : Account<'info,Red>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Purple {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub bump: u8,
}

#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(packed)]

    pub struct Purplelist {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub winners: [ListEntry; 100000],
    pub counter: u64,
    pub total: u64,
    pub bump: u8,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct Rewarding<'info> {
    pub blue : Account<'info, Blue>,
    pub red : Account<'info, Red>,
    pub purple : Account<'info, Purple>,
    pub fees : Account<'info, Fees>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub bluelist: AccountLoader<'info, Bluelist>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub redlist: AccountLoader<'info, Redlist>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub purplelist: AccountLoader<'info, Purplelist>,

}



#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Claiming<'info> {

    #[account(mut)]
    pub purple : Account<'info, Purple>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub purplelist: AccountLoader<'info, Purplelist>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub user : Signer<'info>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct FeeClaim<'info>{
    #[account(mut)]
    pub fees: Account<'info, Fees>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
}
```

THis is my testing code

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { utf8 } from "@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/utils/bytes";
import { Solotesting2 } from "../target/types/solotesting2";
import { LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, sendAndConfirmTransaction } from "@solana/web3.js";

describe("solotesting2", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

  const program = anchor.workspace.Solotesting2 as Program<Solotesting2>;
  const connection = program.provider.connection
  
  const foo = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

  before(async () => {
    const transactionSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
        foo.publicKey,
        1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
    )

    const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } =
        await connection.getLatestBlockhash()

    await connection.confirmTransaction(
        {
        blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight,
        signature: transactionSignature,
        },
        "confirmed"
    )
})

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const [blue] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('blue'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(), 
    ],
    program.programId
    );
    const [red] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('red'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    ],
    program.programId
    );
    const [purple] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('purple'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    ],
    program.programId
    );
    const [bluelist] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('bluelist'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    ],
    program.programId
    );
    const [redlist] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('redlist'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    ],
    program.programId
    );
    const [purplelist] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('purplelist'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    ],
    program.programId
    );
    const [fees] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
      utf8.encode('fees'),
      foo.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    ],
    program.programId
    );

    const tx = await program.methods.initialize().accounts({
      user: foo.publicKey,
      fees: fees,
      blue: blue,
      red: red,
      purple: purple,
      bluelist: bluelist,
      redlist: redlist,
      purplelist: purplelist,
      authority: foo.publicKey,
      systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      
      }).transaction();
      await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [foo])

    
  });
});
```

and this is the error i get

```
1) solotesting2
       Is initialized!:
     Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
```

Comment: Use a try..catch block or check program logs to get a more detailed description of the error. This will make it easier to answer your question

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `utf8.encode` that you're using, you could try doing eg `Buffer.encode('blue')` instead

Answer (score 1):

if the program runned a first time against the devnet then your PDAs are already created, therefore, they can't be created again, since you are using the init constrain, check if the error replicates using the local validator or generating a new program id